# How to correct my Naive Bayes method returning extremely small conditional probabilities?

Tags: python, algorithm, computer-science, data-retrieval

I'm trying to calculate the probability that an email is spam with Naive Bayes. I have a document class to create the documents (fed in from a website), and another class to train and classify documents. My train function calculates all the unique terms in all the documents, all documents in the spam class, all documents in the non-spam class, computes prior probabilities (one for spam, another for ham). Then I use the following formula to store conditional probabilities for each term into a dict

[image: condprob]

Tct = the number of occurances of a term in a given class
Tct' is the # terms in terms in a given class
B' = # unique terms in all documents

classes = either spam or ham
spam = spam, ham = not spam

the issue is that when I use this formula in my code it gives me extremely small conditional probability scores such as 2.461114392596968e-05. I'm quite sure this is because the values for Tct are very small (like 5 or 8) compared to the denominator values of Tct' (which is 64878 for ham and 308930 for spam) and B' (which is 16386). I can't figure out how to get the condprob scores down to something like .00034155, as I can only assume my condprob scores aren't supposed to be as exponentially small as they are. Am I doing something wrong with my calculations? Are the values actually supposed to be this small?
If it helps, my goal is to score a test set of documents and get results like 327.82, 758.80, or 138.66
using this formula

[image: score function]

however, using my small condprob values I only get negative numbers.

**Code**

-Create Document

```
class Document(object):
"""
The instance variables are:
filename....The path of the file for this document.
label.......The true class label ('spam' or 'ham'), determined by whether the filename contains the string 'spmsg'
tokens......A list of token strings.
"""

def __init__(self, filename=None, label=None, tokens=None):
    """ Initialize a document either from a file, in which case the label
    comes from the file name, or from specified label and tokens, but not
    both.
    """
    if label: # specify from label/tokens, for testing.
        self.label = label
        self.tokens = tokens
    else: # specify from file.
        self.filename = filename
        self.label = 'spam' if 'spmsg' in filename else 'ham'
        self.tokenize()

def tokenize(self):
    self.tokens = ' '.join(open(self.filename).readlines()).split()
```

-NaiveBayes

```
class NaiveBayes(object):
def train(self, documents):
    """
    Given a list of labeled Document objects, compute the class priors and
    word conditional probabilities, following Figure 13.2 of your
    book. Store these as instance variables, to be used by the classify
    method subsequently.
    Params:
      documents...A list of training Documents.
    Returns:
      Nothing.
    """
    ###TODO
    unique = []
    proxy = []
    proxy2 = []
    proxy3 = []
    condprob = [{},{}]
    Tct = defaultdict()
    Tc_t = defaultdict()
    prior = {}
    count = 0
    oldterms = []
    old_terms = []
    for a in range(len(documents)):
        done = False
        for item in documents[a].tokens:
            if item not in unique:
                unique.append(item)
            if documents[a].label == "ham":
                proxy2.append(item)
                if done == False:
                    count += 1
            elif documents[a].label == "spam":
                proxy3.append(item)
            done = True
    V = unique
    N = len(documents)
    print("N:",N)
    LB = len(unique)
    print("THIS IS LB:",LB)
    self.V = V
    print("THIS IS COUNT/NC", count)
    Nc = count
    prior["ham"] = Nc / N
    self.prior = prior
    Nc = len(documents) - count
    print("THIS IS SPAM COUNT/NC", Nc)
    prior["spam"] = Nc / N
    self.prior = prior
    text2 = proxy2
    text3 = proxy3
    TctTotal = len(text2)
    Tc_tTotal = len(text3)
    print("THIS IS TCTOTAL",TctTotal)
    print("THIS IS TC_TTOTAL",Tc_tTotal)
    for term in text2:
        if term not in oldterms:
            Tct[term] = text2.count(term)
            oldterms.append(term)
    for term in text3:
        if term not in old_terms:
            Tc_t[term] = text3.count(term)
            old_terms.append(term)
    for term in V:
        if term in text2:
            condprob[0].update({term: (Tct[term] + 1) / (TctTotal + LB)})
        if term in text3:
            condprob[1].update({term: (Tc_t[term] + 1) / (Tc_tTotal + LB)})
    print("This is condprob", condprob)
    self.condprob = condprob

def classify(self, documents):
    """ Return a list of strings, either 'spam' or 'ham', for each document.
    Params:
      documents....A list of Document objects to be classified.
    Returns:
      A list of label strings corresponding to the predictions for each document.
    """
    ###TODO
    #return list["string1", "string2", "stringn"]
    # docs2 = ham, condprob[0] is ham
    # docs3 = spam, condprob[1] is spam
    unique = []
    ans = []
    hscore = 0
    sscore = 0
    for a in range(len(documents)):
        for item in documents[a].tokens:
            if item not in unique:
                unique.append(item)
        W = unique
        hscore = math.log(float(self.prior['ham']))
        sscore = math.log(float(self.prior['spam']))
        for t in W:
            try:
                hscore += math.log(self.condprob[0][t])
            except KeyError:
                continue
            try:
                sscore += math.log(self.condprob[1][t])
            except KeyError:
                continue
        print("THIS IS SSCORE",sscore)
        print("THIS IS HSCORE",hscore)
        unique = []
        if hscore > sscore:
            str = "Spam"
        elif sscore > hscore:
            str = "Ham"
        ans.append(str)

    return ans
```

-Test

```
if not os.path.exists('train'):  # download data
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
import tarfile

urlretrieve('http://cs.iit.edu/~culotta/cs429/lingspam.tgz', 'lingspam.tgz')
tar = tarfile.open('lingspam.tgz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
train_docs = [Document(filename=f) for f in glob.glob("train/*.txt")]
test_docs = [Document(filename=f) for f in glob.glob("test/*.txt")]
test = train_docs

nb = NaiveBayes()
nb.train(train_docs[1500:])
#uncomment when testing classify()
#predictions = nb.classify(test_docs[:200])
#print("PREDICTIONS",predictions)
```

The eventual goal is to be able to classify documents as spam or ham, but I want to work on the conditional probability issue first.

**The Issue**
Are the conditional probability values supposed to be this small? if so, why am I getting strange scores via classify? If not, how do I fix my code to give me the proper condprob values?

**Values**
The current condprob values that I am getting are along the lines of this:
'tradition': 2.461114392596968e-05, 'fillmore': 2.461114392596968e-05, '796': 2.461114392596968e-05, 'zann': 2.461114392596968e-05
condprob is a list containing two dictionaries, the first is ham and the next is spam. Each dictionary maps a term to it's conditional probability. I want to have "normal" small values such as .00031235 not 3.1235e-05.
The reason for this is that when I run the condprob values through the classify method with some test documents I get scores like
THIS IS HSCORE -2634.5292392650663, THIS IS SSCORE -1707.983339196181
when they should look like
THIS IS HSCORE 327.82, THIS IS SSCORE 758.80

**Running Time**
~1 min, 30 sec

Comment: ...Yes, yes it is.

Comment: @CodeSmurf: What sort of values are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: @Tom Barron, I've added more details about my desired results and the results that I'm currently getting

Comment: I'm not a statistician, so I don't know what sorts of values the Bayes algorithm normally produces. I notice that .00031235 and 3.1235e-05 differ by only one decimal position. When you output your values, you could tell python to format them as decimals rather than scientific notation if you'd rather see them in that format. Also, I imagine an option would be to scale the values up by multiplying by 100K or so at some appropriate point in the procedure to "normalize" the final scores.

Answer (score 1):

(You seem to be working with log probabilities, which is very sensible, but I am going to write most of the following for the raw probabilities, which you could get by taking the exponential of the log probabilities, because it makes the algebra easier even if it does in practice mean that you would probably get numerical underflow if you didn't use logs)

As far as I can tell from your code you start with prior probabilities p(Ham) and p(Spam) and then use probabilities estimated from previous data to work out p(Ham) * p(Observed data | Ham) and p(Spam) * p(Observed data | Spam).

Bayes Theorem rearranges p(Obs|Spam) = p(Obs & Spam) / p(Spam) = p(Obs) p(Spam|Obs) / p(Spam) to give you P(Spam|Obs) = p(Spam) p(Obs|Spam)/p(Obs) and you seem to have calculated p(Spam) p(Obs|Spam) = p(Obs & Spam) but not divided by p(Obs). Since there are only two possibilities, Ham and Spam, the easiest thing to do is probably to note that p(Obs) = p(Obs & Spam) + p(Obs & Ham) and so just divide each of your two calculated values by their sum, essentially scaling the values so that they do indeed sum to 1.0.

This scaling is trickier if you start off with log probabilities lA and lB. To scale these I would first of all bring them into range by scaling them both by a rough value as logarithms, so doing a subtraction

lA = lA - max(lA, lB)

lB = lB - max(lA, lB)

Now at least the larger of the two won't overflow. The smaller still might, but I'd rather deal with underflow than overflow. Now turn them into not quite scaled probabilities:

pA = exp(lA)

pB = exp(lB)

and scale properly so they add to zero

truePA = pA / (pA + pB)

truePB = pB / (pA + pB)